# How to use date helper in CodeIgniter to find time conflict?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a database table

```
TABLE subject_loads
id (int)
subject_name (varchar)
time_start (time)
time_end (time)
time_diff (decimal)
```

When I save it on database, it will first check whether the time is not conflicting from the other time already inputed. If it's okay, then compute the time_start and time_end to give me a difference between the two.

Example, `7:30 AM - 8:30 AM` is already in database, when i input `8:00 AM - 9:00 AM` it will say *"conflicting with the other time"*. Only I can input before `7:30 AM` or after `8:30 AM` that doesn't overlap from `7:30 AM - 8:30 AM`.

Can someone help on how to do this?

Comment: Edit question with provided example of time conflict.

Comment: I can't provide an example because i don't know how to do this. Even a snippet. :)

Comment: You need to be able to explain what is date conflict in your mind because it is not known within question. Edit question with expected result values and ones that you consider as conflicted. I.e store 3 rows in such a table, second row to be with good values and third with conflicted values end explain cases when is something in conflict and when is not. Help us to help you.

Comment: I updated my question above sir :). Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check if overlapping values (compared to new value) already exist. You will do that with:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('subject_loads', array('time_start >= ' => $time_start, 'time_end <= ' => $time_end));

if((int)$query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    //similar values exist
}
else
{
    //you are free to insert values
}
```

Second part of issue:

```
$hm1 = "2:12 AM";
$hm2 = "4:41 PM";

$e = conv($hm2) - conv($hm1);

echo $e;

function conv($time)
{
    $expl_time = explode(' ', $time);

    $t = explode(":", $expl_time[0]);

    if ($expl_time[1] == 'PM' || $expl_time[1] == 'pm')
    {
        $t[0] += 12;
    }

    return ($t[0] + round($t[1]/60, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP));
}
```

Comment: Yes!. That's it. Thank u so much sir :)

Comment: I am glad I was able to help. Feel free to [accept answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) as correct one.

Comment: Then, how to compute their difference into a decimal format?

Comment: What is expected value? Seconds? Minutes? Hours? Something else?

Comment: Example, `7:30 AM - 9:00 AM`, their difference is `1.5 hrs` in decimal format. How to do that?

Comment: There are several things need to be considered regarding possible input. Go ahead and ask new question for that one. Describe what are cases of input like every possible `$time_start` and `$time_end`. Try to describe if is possible to place `$time_start` of one date and `$time_end` of another date and other scenarios.

Comment: How do you collect those time values? It would be easier to calculate decimal differenceif 24 hours format would be used.

Comment: I manually inputed the time. But much better if it comes from a bootstrap time-picker that has a meridian. Then it would be a string, example a 12 hour format `8:30 AM`.

Comment: What about dates? Is there possibility for `$end_time` is from different date than `$start_time` or both time values are always within same date?

Comment: It must be the same date.

Comment: There is specific solution. Although need to be checked any edge cases. It is out of question bounds. Please accept answer as correct is solved your issue posted in question.